# jdbc mysql connectivity

Tags: java, servlets, jdbc

I want to make a web application by using jsp servlet and bean am using Netbeans IDE.

I want to know where I should place the database connectivity code so that i can use my database code with every servlet, means I do not want to write the connectivity code in everypage where I need to use the database.

Please help me to find and how should I move?

Comment: accept some answers. 16 questions, none accepted.

Answer (score 2):

Just put all the JDBC stuff in its own class and import/call/use it in the servlet.

E.g.

```
public class UserDAO {
    public User find(String username, String password) {
        User user = new User();
        // Put your JDBC code here to fill the user (if found).
        return user;
    }
}
```

With

```
import com.example.dao.UserDAO;
import com.example.model.User;

public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private UserDAO userDAO;

    public void init() throws ServletException {
        userDAO = new UserDAO(); // Or obtain by factory.
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        String username = request.getParameter("username");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");
        User user = userDAO.find(username, password);
        if (user != null) {
            // Login.
        } else {
            // Error: unknown user.
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one idea how to do it:

1. Make a class named `DBConnection` with a static factory method `getNewDBConnection`
2. During application startup, verify that your db connection is valid, and using `ServletContextListener`, set up the `DBConnection` class so the mentioned method will always return a new connection
3. Use throughout your code `DBConnection.getNewDBConnection()`.

I'll leave the boilerplate and exception handling up to you. There are more elegant ways to do this, using JPA for example, but this is outside of this answer's scope.

Beware of above idea. I have only written it; but haven't tried it and proven it correct.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the include mechanisms:

> <%@ include file="filename" %>

Detail here http://java.sun.com/j2ee/tutorial/1_3-fcs/doc/JSPIntro8.html

Answer (score 0):

If you make connection from the servlets, you could create a BaseServlet class that extends HttpServlet, than your actual server have to extends BaseServlet rather then HttpServlet.
Now you can write the connectivity code just in the BaseServlet and just use it in your pseudo-servlets (extending BaseServlet).